# requestAnimationFrameの引数で指定するコールバック関数に、引数を渡したい

Tags: javascript

**現状**
・挙動は問題ないのですが、ループ数だけ関数が必要なので簡潔に書きたい

```
function loop1(){
  if(条件分岐){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop2);
    return;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop1);
}
function loop2(){
  if(条件分岐){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop1);
    return;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop2);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop1);
```

---

**やりたいことのイメージ**
・requestAnimationFrameの引数では、コールバック関数に引数を渡せないようですが、同等内容にするにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
・最終的にやりたいことは、現状2つある関数を1つにしたいことなので、別に下記イメージではなくても構いません
※条件分岐はループ内容に依存しています

```
function loop(n){
  if(条件分岐){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop(2));
    return;
  }else if(条件分岐){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop(1));
    return;
  }
  if(条件分岐){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop(1));
  }else if(条件分岐){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop(2));
  }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind()` してください。単純にやるなら、

```
requestAnimationFrame(loop.bind(null, 2));
```

のように書き換えます。

こういう場合は状態を管理するオブジェクトを作って、そのオブジェクトのメソッドを rAF に渡すほうがよりJavaScriptらしいと思います。

```
var Animator = function() {
  this.state = 0;
  this.boundOnAnimationFrame = this.onAnimationFrame.bind(this);
  requestAnimationFrame(this.boundOnAnimationFrame);
};
Animator.prototype.onAnimationFrame = function() {
  if (条件分岐) {
     this.state = 2;
  } else if (条件分岐) {
     this.state = 1;
  }
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(this.boundOnAnimationFrame);
};
```

Comment: 「bind()使用する方法」、「状態管理するオブジェクトを作成する方法」、何れも期待通り動作することを確認しました。発想が異なる実装方法を複数提示いただいたので、大変勉強になりましたー

Answer (score 1):

クロージャで対応するのは如何でしょうか？

```js
$(function(){
  
  function loopStart(conditions){
    var repeat = true;
    
    var loop = function(){
      $('<div></div>').text('条件:' + conditions + '[' + repeat + ']' ).appendTo('body');
      
      if(repeat){
        repeat = false;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      }  
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  
  $('#btn1').click( function(){ loopStart('btn1') } );
  $('#btn2').click( function(){ loopStart('btn2') } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">条件1</button>
<button id="btn2">条件2</button>
```